# BitmapImage isDownloading always true

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

I'm trying to load a bitmapImage, while waiting for it to load up to 10 seconds. 
For that, I need to identify when the image has finished downloading.
So I'm checking the 'isDownloading' property in order to identify whether the image is indeed being downloaded.

Here's the code:

```
Uri imageUri = new Uri(imageSource);
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
if (bitmapImage.IsDownloading)
{
   bitmapImage.DownloadCompleted += (s, e) => _autoResetEvent.Set();
   var imageLoadingTimer = new Timer(10000);
   imageLoadingTimer.Elapsed += (s, e) => _autoResetEvent.Set();
   imageLoadingTimer.Start();
   _autoResetEvent.WaitOne();                
}
```

Problem is, though the image is indeed being downloaded and finished downloading within 0.4 seconds according to Fiddler, the DownloadCompleted event never fires and the isDownloading property is always true.

Any assistance will be much appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: How is image being download as seen in fiddler?  Is it TCP or HTTP?  Does fiddler show any headers or connection closing?  Is image a base 64 stream or GZIP?  TCP you cannot tell if a receive binary message finishes unless the connection closes of a byte count is given at beginning of message.

Comment: The DownloadCompleted event is executed in the UI thread, which is blocked by the WaitOne call.

Comment: @jdweng thanks, fiddler opens a https connection and downloads the whole image - I can see in the response, under the imageview tab, the picture i was trying to download. I'm not sure about the other stuff you asked, what do you suggest I'll check next?

Comment: If you are using a blocking http response, then when the response returns you have the entire message.  No need for any async method if the response is coming back in 0.4 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are handling an event that gets raised when the download has completed, you shouldn't wait/block at all.

Just move the code that you want to execute after the download has completed to the event handler and get rid of the `AutoResetEvent`:

```
string imageSource = "";
Uri imageUri = new Uri(imageSource);
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
if (bitmapImage.IsDownloading)
{
    void OnCompleted()
    {
        //...
    }

    bitmapImage.DownloadCompleted += (s, e) => OnCompleted();
    var imageLoadingTimer = new Timer(10000);
    imageLoadingTimer.Elapsed += (s, e) => OnCompleted();
    imageLoadingTimer.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a race condition to me. The image download is completed after you enter the `if (bitmapImage.IsDownloading)` block, but before you assign the event handler. As a result, the event handler is never fired.

Reorder your statements in the following manner.

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.DownloadCompleted += (s, e) => ... // Whatever
bitmapImage.UriSource = imageUri;
```

This should ensure that the DownloadCompleted handler is already in place by the time the file is downloaded.